# IP Masking control for textbox in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to apply IP Masking for a text in asp.net.I trying to use the below plugin.
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
But with this plugin i am facing an issue. It is always expecting 3 digits in all 4 4 octects. If i am trying to give an ip Address 10.2.3.3 the text box is clearing when comes out from the text box. I need to disable IP textboxes sometimes.
For me masking should work for like formats
10.2.3.3, 100.2.33.33,10.2.34.34,10.22.333.444
Is there any fix for this  or
I need a IP Masking which was good and working..please share if any

Comment: 10.22.333.444 this is not a valid IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<script src="https://jquery-input-ip-address-control.googlecode.com/files/jquery.input-ip-address-control-1.0.min.js">
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('.ipv4').ipAddress();
        $('.ipv6').ipAddress({v:6});
    });
</script>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="ipv4" />
</body>
```

Documentation/source is at: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-input-ip-address-control/

Comment: hi

i tried jquery-input-ip-address-control. In that ipv4 is working fine but ipv6 is not working properly. I tried to enter 1122:0000:00:00:00:00. It is not taking only one letter after that it's not taking anything
please help me..any help much appreciated

Comment: Seems to work for me. Try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MUzuL/
I manage to enter 1122:0000:00:00:00:99 in the mask.